# Is there a generic word for "thread or process"?

Tags: terminology, process-scheduling, threads

I'm writing about a problem that could be caused by race conditions between multiple threads, or OS-level processes on the same machine or different machines, or VM-level processes like the Erlang VM has.

In this context, the fact of parallel execution is the important part; the language or memory-sharing model is irrelevant.

**Is there a generic word that means "thread or process"?** "Concurrent unit of execution" is the best attempt I have so far, but it sounds awkward to me.

Comment: Andrew S. Tanenbaum mentions term "concurrent operation" in his Modern Operating Systems book.

Comment: Concurrent thread?

Answer (score 6):

A process is a context with one or more threads of execution (concurrent with other threads of execution, either in the same process, or perhaps in other processes), *and* with its own address space (and usually other resources such as open file descriptors, IPC mechanisms, etc.).  More subtle details and implications are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Threads_vs._processes)

So, if address space (and other such resources) isn't relevant to your discussion (and it's probably not given your description), then I would say that the word **thread** is sufficient to describe the entities involved in your discussion.  Historically **task** has also been used to describe a thread, and indeed it was perhaps the first word used to describe this concept (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#History)).

(Note of course there's a difference between concurrent threads and parallel threads -- concurrent threads may be executed in parallel, but it is not necessary for operations to occur in parallel for them to suffer from the issues related to concurrency.)